# ArangoDB Hash Index Ignored (?)

Tags: arangodb

My database currently consists of 3 document collections with between 250k to 1.5M documents. I set my own document `_key`s and have added Hash indexes on a few toplevel fields and lists (the lists containing references to other keys or (indexed) fields).

The collections A and C have an n:m relationship via B. The query I first came up with looks like this:

```any
for a in collection_a
    filter a.name != null
    filter length(a.bs) > 0
    limit 1
    return {
          'akey': a._key
        , 'name': a.name
        , 'cs': (
            for b in collection_b
                filter b.a == a._key
                for c in collection_c
                    filter b.c == c._key
                    return c.name
        )
    }
```

This is excruciatingly slow. I also tried other approaches such as making the middle `for` a `for b in a.bs` (bs being a list of keys of collection_b documents).

Printing out `explain()` of the above query returns an immense cost and `getExtra()` indicates no indexes were used:

```any
{ 
  "stats" : { 
    "writesExecuted" : 0, 
    "writesIgnored" : 0, 
    "scannedFull" : 6009930, 
    "scannedIndex" : 0 
  }, 
  "warnings" : [ ] 
}
```

An alternate approach works as fast as I'd expected it to be in the first place:

```any
for a in collection_a
    filter a.name != null
    filter length(a.bs) > 0
    limit 1
    return {
          'akey': a._key
        , 'name': a.name
        , 'cs': (
            for b in a.bs
                return DOCUMENT(collection_c , DOCUMENT(collection_b, b).c ).name
        )
    }
```

But even here, no indexes appear to be used:

```any
{ 
  "stats" : { 
    "writesExecuted" : 0, 
    "writesIgnored" : 0, 
    "scannedFull" : 3000, 
    "scannedIndex" : 0 
  }, 
  "warnings" : [ ] 
}
```

---

One thing that may already explain this is, that hash indexes don't work for elements of a list (or I made a mistake when creating them)? The `getExtras()` of the second example would hint at this.

My expectation, however, would be that arangodb indexes all elements of the lists (such as `a.bs`) and the query optimizer should realize that indexed attributes are used in the query.

If I run `for b in collection_b filter b.a == 'somekey'`, I get an instantaneous result as expected. And that's just running the middle `for` in isolation. Same behaviour when I run the innermost `for` in isolation.

Is this a bug? Is there an explanation for this behaviour? Am I doing something wrong in the first query? The AQL Examples themself use nested `for`s so that's what I naturally ended up trying first.

Comment: We change the query optimizier from 2.2 to 2.3. Which version of ArangoDB do you use?

Comment: I'm running arangodb 2.3.0 (amd64) on debian testing

Comment: Thanks for that. A partial fix for the subquery not using the index should be included in this commit:
https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/commit/3be52c0fe4c426e547135e69f7f32e0ccc55b02c

Comment: Thank you! Just verified this reduces the query time down to about 6sec from almost 30sec (in a totally non-scientific test)!

Comment: I also made another modification that pipes optimized plans through the same optimizer stage again, enabling potentially even more index usage: https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/commit/0319a4640053c36b3879569f88ffce977c4891d7

Comment: Very nice! This makes the query pretty much instantaneous!! But I just noticed, the limit parameter works only up to 199. Above that, the AQL Editor just runs forever (hangs?) or returns ERROR. More queries after that with a limit below 200 still work. This applies to both of your commits. In the log, there is (sometimes) something like `ERROR unknown shape id 18154` and others with a different number in the 18-19k range.

Comment: I remember there was an issue with the AQL editor in the web interface showing the "Query is executing" thing forever. I am not sure if this is related to the problem you are seeing, but when result sets grew bigger than 1000 records, the "Query is executing" didn't go away in some cases. This was fixed in 2.3.1.

Comment: @stackmagic can you check if there disappears with 2.3.1? Thanks

Comment: Performance is good but it's still the same with a limit of 200 and higher.

Comment: With a limit of 200 (or higher) the Editor runs like forever or do you get an error?

Comment: Last time I tried this, It just ended up printing 'ERROR' in the AQL console. It only seemed to hang on earlier versions of the devel branch (Nov 26, error only is Dec 4). I'd have to go back and try to re-create this 'old' dataset to thoroughly re-test this.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in release 2.3.2.

**clarification**: the query you posted is correct. There was an issue in release 2.3.0 that prevented indexes in subqueries being used.
This issue has been fixed in release 2.3.2. 
The initial query you posted should properly use indexes in 2.3.2. If there is a hash index available on the join attributes, it should be used because the query only contains equality lookups.